# Extending vector fields defined on open sets

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I'm interested in finding sufficient conditions for when a vector field $X$ defined on an open subset of a smooth manifold $M$ can be extended. It is clear that this can't always be done. For example $X(t) = \frac{1}{t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ on $(0,\infty)$ admits no continuous extension on $\mathbb{R}$.

In particular let's consider a manifold $M = (0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $(t,r,\phi)$ where $(r, \phi)$ are the usual spherical coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$. I want to prove that if $\widetilde{M}$ is an extension of $M$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ can be extended onto $\widetilde{M}$. An instance where this occurs is in the [Milne Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milne_model). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't see why your claim should be true. $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be "rolled up" and embedded as a subset of the infinite cylinder $C = \mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{R}$, the image being, say, $C \setminus \{-1\}\times\mathbb{R}$. Approaching the removed line from one way $\partial_\phi$ points up. Approaching the removed line from the other it points down. There is no continuous extension. There must be additional assumptions that you are omitting in your question statement.

Comment: I think a lot of what is unclear is: "what do you mean by an extension?" If you just mean $\tilde{M}$ contains a diffeomorphic copy of $M$ as a subset, then I don't think you have any chance of the statement you want being true. But maybe you mean something else which puts stronger conditions on what $\tilde{M}$ could be.